# Pull same key out of multiple objects

Tags: javascript, format, svelte

I have JSON data like this

```json
{
"_id": "621813467b8cfa82889de451",
"name": "Test Student",
"parentEmail": "test@example.com",
"teacher": "Mr Teacher",
"scores": [
    {
    "Raise Hand": "0",
    "Ask For Help": "2",
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "date": "2022-02-24"
    },
    {
    "Raise Hand": "2",
    "Ask For Help": "4",
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "date": "2022-02-24"
    }
],
"goals": [
    {
    "type": "Multi Choice",
    "name": "Raise Hand",
    "_id": "6218140f7b8cfa82889de45f"
    },
    {
    "type": "Multi Choice",
    "name": "Ask For Help",
    "_id": "621814187b8cfa82889de470"
    }
],
"__v": 4
}
```

and I am trying to get the "scores" data to have a bar graph with chart.js (Use date as x axis and the scores for the y axis), but I don't know how to extract the data dynamically.

I need it to be dynamic so a user can add a new goal through the GUI and submit a score for a new day and either a new graph is added or a new bar is added to the bar graph.

I'm also using svelte.

This is what I have so far:

```js
//dummy data to resemble data from database
const students = [
    {
    email: "ads",
        "Raise Hand": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        date: "2022-2-23",
        comment: "Good",
    },
    {
    email: "ads",
        "Raise Hand": 3,
        "Ask For Help": 4,
        date: "2022-2-24",
        comment: "No Comment",
    },
    {
    email: "ads",
        "Raise Hand": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        date: "2022-2-25",
        comment: "No Comment",
    },
    {
    email: "ads",
        "Raise Hand": 3,
        "Ask For Help": 4,
        "Do Work": 3,
        date: "2022-2-25",
        comment: "No Comment",
    },
    {
    email: "ads",
        "Raise Hand": 1,
        "Ask For Help": 2,
        "Do Work": 3,
        "New One": 4,
        date: "2022-2-25",
        comment: "No Comment",
    },
];

let data = [];

let newKey;

getKeys();

async function getKeys() {
    for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        for (let key in students[i]) {
            if (
        key == "email" ||
                key == "date" ||
                key.toLowerCase().includes("comment")
            ) {
                continue;
            } else {
                newKey = key;
                const newValue = students[i][key];
                const amountOfKeys = Object.keys(students[i]).length;

                await checkKey(key, i)
            }
        }
    }
  filter(data)
}

function checkKey(key, num) {
  let newArr = [];
  let tempObj = {}
    if (key == newKey) {
    tempObj[key] = students[num][key]
    tempObj["date"] = students[num]["date"]
        data.push(tempObj);
    // console.log(data)
    }
}

function filter(arr) {
  console.log(arr)
  let temp;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    temp = arr[i]
    arr.splice(0, 1)
    console.log(temp)
    console.log(arr)
  }
}
```

Edit: Not sure if it matters but on the backend I'm using NodeJs with express and mongoDB

Comment: If I may ask the following: (a) what do you want the final data shape to look like (i.e. the shape of the data you will feed to your chart), (b) what are the possible input keys/attributes other than the scores, date, email and comment, if any and (c) which keys/attributes do you want to preserve for your chart data other than the scores and the date (i.e. which keys/attributes can/cannot be safely discarded)?

Comment: @ThomasHennes a) I want the data to look something like this [{x:'2016-12-25', y:20}, {x:'2016-12-26', y:10}] b} the user can create a multi choice question with any name (Ex. "Raise Hand") and choose a number between 0 and 4. c) I want everything except email and anything with "comment" in the name like I have here: "key.toLowerCase().includes("comment")"

Comment: Also I want the keys to either be grouped together in one graph with a different bar for each key group or a new graph for each group (so a graph for raise hand, one for ask for help, and another one for whatever the user chooses (no limit)

Comment: So, any key that's not `date`, `email` (discarded) or contains `comment` (discarded) can be assumed to be a type of score? And how do you obtain `y` in the final data from the different score keys? Or does a chart only represent one type of score at any time (i.e. "raise hand", "ask for help", etc.)?

Comment: Ah your second comment answers my second question, thanks.

Comment: @ThomasHennes I want to use date as one axis so you can see improvement through time. Yes only represent one score at a time. I can handle dynamically adding the graphs themselves but I just need the data separated.

Comment: Last questions: can there be multiple entries with the same date (for instance, different students, or multiple entries for the same student on one given date) and if so are the scores (of any given type) to be added together? Is there a graph by student (based on `email`), or are all student scores to be added together?

Comment: @ThomasHennes there can be multiple entries with the same date (with the same student) though most likely for testing (each student will have 1 extry per day). Each student is given an Id by mongoDB as seen in the JSON data and the JS gets only one student at a time when graphing the data (fetch(http://localhost:3000/students/621813467b8cfa82889de451)). I am keeping all the students scores separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the data transformation function I came up with. The data output is an array of object with the format `{ x: 'YYYY-MM-DD', y: { [key]: score, [key]: score, ... } }`, each date being unique and sorted from oldest to newest.

```js
    function formatData(dataIn) {
        // step 1, sort input array by date, filter unnecessary data, pre-format
        // input and build a template object of all possible score keys
        const scoreObj = {};
        const data = dataIn
            .sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date))
            .map((d) => {
                const y = {};
                Object.keys(d).forEach((k) => {
                    if (k === 'email' || /comment/i.test(k)) {
                        delete d[k];
                    } else if (k !== 'date') {
                        if (!scoreObj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                            scoreObj[k] = 0;
                        }
                        y[k] = d[k];
                    }
                })
                return {
                    x: d.date,
                    y,
                };
            });
        // step 2, reduce sorted/filtered/formatted input array into array
        // of unique date entries (x) with associated score object (y)
        const dataOut = data.reduce((acc, d, i) => {
            // if date entry already exists
            if (i > 0 && acc[acc.length - 1].x === d.x) {
                for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(d.y)) {
                    acc[acc.length - 1].y[k] += v;
                }
                return acc;
            }
            // if new date entry
            return [ ...acc, {
                x: d.x,
                y: Object.assign({ ...scoreObj }, d.y),
            } ];
        }, [])
        return dataOut;
    }
```

The transformation function works in two distinct steps. Step 1 sort of preprocesses data, by:

- sorting the data by ascending dates
- filtering the unwanted/unnecessary keys (`email` and anything containing `comment` (ignoring case))
- pre-formatting the data entries into objects of shape `{ x: <date>, y: { <key/score pairs> } }`
- creating a template, zero-score object containing all possible score keys

Step 2 then takes in the pre-processed data, and uses `Array.reduce` to group entries by unique dates, and tally scores for that date. Namely, for each input entry, two outcomes are possible:

- an entry does not exist for this date ; a new entry for the date is created, merging the template score object with the actual score values for the input entry (this guarantees that all possible score keys exist for any given unique date, even though their value might be 0) ; this entry is then pushed onto the output array
- an entry already exists for this date ; because the input array is already sorted, we only have to check the last entry written into the output array to see if the date entry already exists (and we only do that from the 2nd input entry onwards, since the output array will be empty when the first input entry is evaluated) ; we then add the score values to the existing entry's score keys and proceed to the next input entry

The output data is flexible enough to leave you the choice of putting all score keys into a single graph, or having one graph per score key (using `map`).

Finally, in Svelte, given an input array named `students` for instance, you can keep the output data up-to-date with a single reactive statement:
`$: graphData = formatData(students);`

See [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/651cd3ee3ad844938e117bff438ce7e3?version=3.46.4) for a bare bones example (no graphs, just raw data output).

Comment: So I should be able to just plug the output into a chart?

Comment: That's for you to figure out. All I can say is the output data is clean and formatted according to your specs, so if any transformation is required it should be minimal ; for instance if you want to have a chart with only one type of score (e.g. 'Raise Hand'), you would feed it `graphData.map(o => ({ x: o.x, y: o.y['Raise Hand']}))`.

Comment: The format of my output should be pretty clear from both my detailed answer and the REPL example.

Comment: Ok thank you. I've only been using JS for a few months so I'm not familiar with all the features. But I'll figure it out.

Comment: If/when you come across a specific implementation problem, open up a new question, I'm sure someone (myself included) will happily assist you.

Comment: Also, if you have any question regarding any of the steps in the formatting function in my answer, or about a statement that is not clear, feel free to ask!